# MySQL error: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, database

I have a couple of Joomla 3.3.6 websites, and suddenly this morning I started to get random error messages, like this:

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' SQL=DELETE  FROM `#####_session` WHERE `time` < '1414616481'

and this:

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `#####_session` WHERE `session_id` = '5e5f2d5ee6daf15c2740e3e211a27941' LIMIT 0, 1

Is it possible that my websites have been hacked? These are live websites, and I haven't made any changes (not even visited the admin area) for weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an error with your database server rather than your website.

Are you by any chance using a Hostgator Reseller account? Hostgator is currently experiencing problems with some of their servers, and I think it's been like that all day. Check http://forums.hostgator.com/oct-29-02-00-emergency-maintenance-t328219.html for more information on the error.

If you're using another host, I suggest you contact their support team, maybe they're able to help.

Comment: Great guess, turns out that Hostgator is causing the problem, as you said. Thanks for the info, I just hope they solve it soon.

Answer (score 2):

this error is appear when your table corrupted.
you can repair your table and error gone.
login into your phpmyadmin , then click on your database name, then select your corrupted table, scroll down to bottom of page, in a dropdown box select repair.

Answer (score 2):

1) Extract your database using phpmyadmin

2) Edit the downloaded database Yourdatabse.sql  in any editor and replace all Engine = "InnoDB"  with  Engine = "MYISAM".

3) Upload the database back (import using phymyadmin).

MAKE SURE YOU TAKE BACKUP OF YOUR SITE using Akeeba Backup or another way before you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I find it rather odd that this error has started occurring all of a sudden. I believe the InnoDB engine was introduced from MySQL 5.1 onwards (not 100% sure). So, firstly:

1. Check your MySQL version. If you're on 5.1 or below then get your host to update it.
2. Get on contact with your host and ask them if they have for some odd reason downgraded your MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

HostGator.com HostGator

> Hello, and thank you for contacting Hostgator regarding your server
>   stability issue.
>
> Thank you for the update! We've confirmed a problem with the InnoDB storage engine in your MySQL instance.
>
> We're repairing some
>   databases used by MySQL now, as well as clearing spam from the mail
>   queue that was sent by the compromised account tbldev1.
>
> Once this is
>   complete, we will continue to work on the MySQL software to restore
>   the InnoDB engine. Please stand by for further updates.