# Joomla 2.5 site shows this code

Tags: joomla-2.5, fix-my-code

[Joomla 2.5 site](http://www.honestbulksms.com) shows this code:

```
Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' SQL=INSERT INTO `josk6_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('de4e7a49e0bc880dc85f8349f0b44054', 0, '1450620422')
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Relax, I don't think your site has been hacked. Have a read of this and see if it applies to you: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5002/mysql-error-unknown-storage-engine-innodb

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to JSE. If your site was working and this error has just happened then it is likely that your server is experiencing an error. Contact your hosting provider.

However if you are setting up a new site then it is possible that there is either a configuration error or the server is not offering `InnoDB` as a storage engine.

Either way if it is not your server then you need to contact your hosting provider. If it is your server then you need to ensure that it is setup with the `InnoDB` storage engine.

Comment: Hi @Uzoma Tony  if this was helpful and answered your question, for the sake of closing this off, please accept the answer.